# Get Feature that was snapped to in New Snapping Environment

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, snapping

I asked this over at the ESRI forums but lack of activity over there made me post here as well.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the feature that something was just snapped to in the [Snapping Environment](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001s1000000.htm) in ArcGIS 10? I have code that will do this in the classic snapping mode but I would like to take advantage of the new snapping environment.

In classic snapping you could loop through the [IFeatureSnapAgent.FeatureCache](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002000000141000000) and perfrom a HitTest to see which feature was just snapped to.

I see you can get the location of the snapped point via [ISnappingEnvironment.PointSnapper.Snap()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Snap_Method/0016000002v3000000/), but this does not expose any information about what was snapped to. I see you can add/clear/update a geometry cache on the [ISnappingEnvironment.PointSnapper](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PointSnapper_Property/001600000316000000/) but you can't get any of the items in cache. I'm not too sure that would be helped either way since its just geometries and not features. I guess in theory you could perform a spatial query against each layer in the map with the location of the [ISnappingResult](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISnappingResult_Interface/001600000320000000/) but I don't see this as something that is feasible performance wise.

I am missing something or has anyone else dealt with this limitation of the new Snapping Environment?

Matt

Comment: I'm sure it is something that is caught. as you can see the popup report the object layer prior to snapping

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You can get the layer name from the SnapTip via the ISnappingResult description property. However it is not a reliable source to get the layer name because the user can turn snap tips off and the property would not be populated.